# what was this C++ feature called again?

Tags: c++, foreach, std-pair

Let's say I am iterating over a `std::vector` of `std::pair`s like this:

```
for (const auto& [one, two] : pairs)
{
    std::cout << one << two;
}
```

What was the language mechanism called that allowed to "alias" `std::pair::first` to user defined identifiers like `one`? There was also an article on cppreference about that, but I can't find it because I can't remember what it's called!

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/structured_binding

Comment: @RedBox the question title can be definitely improved!